# Compute the Jacobson radical in Quaternion Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quaternions

Let $B$ be a finite-dimensional $F$-algebra. The Jacobson radical of $B$ is the intersection of all maximal left ideals of $B$.

The following is an exercise from Voight's Quaternion Algebras.

> Suppose the characteristic of $F$ is not equal to $2$. Compute the Jacobson radical of $B$ with basis $1, i, j, ij$ satisfying $i^2=a, j^2=0,$ and $ij=-ji.$

I'm trying to compute the Jacobson radical of quaternion orders given an explicit basis and this seems like a good exercise to get an idea of how to compute the Jacobson radical. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show that $j$ must lie in the radical? Then consider the quotient $B/\langle j\rangle$.

Comment: If j^2 is zero then that algebra is not a quaternion algebra.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Perhaps they simply meant "in <book title>" rather than "in <algebraic structure>".

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yeah, the exercise was meant to show that the given algebra is not semi-simple and hence not a quaternion algebra. Sorry if the title of the post was misleading.